# Retrieving all but one value

Tags: python

I'm looking to retrieve all but one value from a list:

```
 ll = ['a','b','c']
 nob = [x for x in ll if x !='b']
```

Is there any simpler, more pythonic way to do this, with sets perhaps?

Comment: How important is it that the original list remain unmutated? Are the values unique? Maybe `.remove()` is appropriate here.

Comment: I think what you have now is pretty simple and pythonic already. If you used sets instead it would be a little simpler but would abandon the order of your elements.

Comment: so 'b' occurs only once in the list?

Comment: @Chris_Rands, Yes.  This code comes from a list of fields, and I want to skip one.

Comment: Another option could be to use filter: `nob = filter(lambda x: x!='b', ll)` but I think what you have is as pythonic as it gets.

Comment: As Kevin says you could do remove if you want to mutate the list, `.remove()`  short-circuits once 'b' is found, otherwise if you're doing this a lot, consider changing your data structure to something like a dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given that the element is unique in the list, you can use `list.index`

```
i = l.index('b')
l = ll[:i] +ll[i+1:]
```

another possibility is to use `list.remove`

```
ll.remove('b') #notice that ll will change underneath here
```

whatever you do, you'll always have to step through the list and compare each element, which gets slow for long lists. However, using the index, you'll get the index of the first matching element and can operate with this alone, thus avoiding to step through the remainder of the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_ = ['a', 'b', 'c']

list_.pop(1)
```

You can also use .pop, and pass the index column, or name, that you want to pop from the list. When you print the list you will see that it stores ['a', 'c'] and 'b' has been "popped" from it.